# Do those stemming make sense in OpenNLP?

Tags: opennlp, stemming

I just installed openNLP and tested some stemming. Those stemming results look suspicious to me.

```
people => peopl
excellent => excel
beautiful => beauti
```

I am not sure these are the original output of OpenNLP, or my installation has some problem which can't produce correct results.

Can someone help me verify these? Thank you really.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, that makes sense. From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stemming):

> The stem need not be identical to the morphological root of the word; it is usually sufficient that related words map to the same stem, even if this stem is not in itself a valid root.

Lemmatizer is the tool that returns the morphological root. It gets the inflected word and a pos tag and returns the lemma. You can check how to use it in [OpenNLP Manual](http://opennlp.apache.org/docs/1.8.0/manual/opennlp.html#tools.lemmatizer).